# Unir dos conexiones en una PHP MYSQLI

Tags: php, html, html5, mysqli

Tengo montada una página web que accede a unos datos en concreto con basededatos.tabla basededatos1.tabla (de esta forma están montadas la consultas)

el problema que ahora me han dicho que basededatos1 está en otro servidor y no se como crear dos conexiones y poder hacer las consultas uniendo las dos conexiones, dado que para lanzar una consulta es:

`$consulta= $mysqli->query($query);` (`$mysqli` es la conexión. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya que son dos conexiones distintas (es intranscendental si son el mismo server o distintos), debes manejar las queries de forma separada. Utilizar distintos conectores y correr tus queries sobre una u otra de acuerdo a donde estén los datos. Finalmente, hacer la unión de datos mediante código, si es que llegase a ser necesario hacer la unión de datos.

Comment: Eso es lo que estaba pensando, dos conexiones con dos variables distintas, etc... Pero me encuentro el fallo en el logueo de la web, cosa que antes funcionaba bien y al crear dos objetos
 `$mysqli2 = new mysqli($server1, $usuario1, $pass1, $bd1);´
me da el error, la sentencia está vacia

Comment: logueo = login o logueo = guardar logs? estás seguro que se logra conectar la segunda instancia del conector? el error puede ir por muchos lados, es necesario ir cerrando el circulo alrededor del error

Comment: @WindStone tienes que hacer las consultas como te dice Pablo, pero no significa repetir las consultas idénticas cada vez. A lo mejor tendrás que ampliar tu pregunta si te quedaron dudas

Answer (score 0):

no se si entiendo correctamente tu pregunta.

Si **$mysqli** es la conexión, con una de las dos BDs (evidentemente es con la que tienes los datos de conexión), para conectar a la otra, puedes volver a instanciar **$mysqli**, con los datos de conexión de la otra BDs (por lo menos te va a cambiar la IP), o bien crear una instancia de conexión diferente con esos mismos datos, si requieres trabajar simultáneamente con ambas BDs.

Con dos instancias de tipo conexión es más flexible y las estés usando o no, se hace más comprensible, así tendrías por ejemplo **$mysqli1** y **$mysqli2**. Ahora sólo tienes que saber donde están los datos que requieres en cada momento para hacer las consultas con la instancia adecuada.

Answer (score -1):

> *el problema que ahora me han dicho que basededatos1 está en otro servidor*

Me haría tres preguntas para dar con la mejor solución:

**(A). Si no es obligatorio que las dos BD esté separadas**

Si no lo es, lo mejor sería tener las dos BD en el mismo servidor, pues te **evitas el que tu sitio dependa de otro dominio**. Suponte que el dominio donde está la otra BD está caído, no funciona durante unas horas o un día, o es hackeado... Las partes de tu dominio que muestran datos de esa BD "externa" no funcionaría, quizá muchas páginas de tu web se muestren en blanco.

Si no hay otra salida y las BD deben estar en servidores distintos, entonces hay varias posibilidades de llamar los datos de tu BD "externa". Lo más seguro, creo, sería consultar dicha BD "externa" en forma de API. Consultarías URLs de la misma que te devolverían los valores que necesitas en formato JSON y presentas dichos formatos en tu página. Pero... para eso debes tener acceso al otro dominio y programar tu API para que devuelva los datos que necesitas.

**(B). Si las dos BD pueden estar en el mismo dominio**

Si esto es posible, ¡excelente! Sería una mejor solución que **(A)**. Pues puedes crear dos conexiones a cada BD, como se ha explicado en respuestas y comentarios anteriores. Pedir a cada BD los datos que necesites y mostrarlos en tu página. Así dejas de depender de que el otro dominio funcione o no.

Pero... aún me haría otra pregunta.

**(C). Si es obligatorio que las dos BD estén separadas**

Si no lo es, lo mejor de todo sería tener una BD única con todas las tablas de BD1 y BD2.

Ganarías en rapidez y eficacia en tu web. Tener una conexión suplementaria siempre tiene su precio, así como consultar dos BD en lugar de una. La diferencia se nota también a la hora de programar.

**(D). En resumen**

Todo dependerá de lo que se pueda o no se pueda en tu caso y del uso que quieras darle. Pero, dentro de las posibilidades, elige lo que sea más práctico y más eficaz.